# dynamically comparing two csv files in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a number of csv files.
My requirement right now is to compare them and give out another csv file which gives me the matching records of those csv files.
I have named the two files as previous and current.
now, when I add another csv file, My current file should become my previous file and my previous file needs to be discarded.
All this needs to happen dynamically
Please help me out in this assignment.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code you had written and where you got a problem?

Comment: Can you provide the code or the csv files?

Comment: I am really sorry, i don't have the code and the csv files are enterprise data